# RSA.FromXmlString 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to do a unit test on my Hybrid encryption and decryption but I'm having an error of 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'.

I'm calling the declared as string private, which in result it's getting the private key. Then this method calls the method 2, which is supposed to Digital Sign a file using the private key.

```
    byte[] sign = new Encryp().DigitalSign(privatekey, memFile);
```

Method 2:

```
    public byte[] DigitalSign(string privateKey, MemoryStream data)
    {
        RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
        RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey); //Line which triggers the error

        byte[] hash = Hash(dataToBeSigned.ToArray());
        byte[] signture = RSA.SignHash(hash, "SHA512");

        return signture;
    }
```

Comment: which version of .net core

Comment: @Gauravsa 2.1.8 preview

Comment: ok, i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its .Net Core, it doesnot have a FromXmlString. However, you can try using this as extension methods:

https://gist.github.com/Jargon64/5b172c452827e15b21882f1d76a94be4/

In .net core 3.0, its available. Either update to .net core 3 or use the extension methods. hope it helps.

Comment: So if I update my .Net Core to 3.0, should .FromXmlString work ?

Comment: Well, I have all the project in .Net core 2.1.8, will it affect the whole project if I update it to 3.0 ?

Comment: ok, then you can use the extension method provided in the link

Comment: if it works, please mark it as answer. thanks and have agreat new year

Answer (score 0):

if you work on .netcor2 it does not support.after .net core 3 its support.